# Zk Notify multiple view

Tags: javascript, binding, zk, eventqueue

I'm working on a project using zk framework. I have many users who can use the application at the same time.

If one of them change a value of a field and fire the `@notifychange` I want to update the views of all other users.

For example if all the users are in the same page

```
<window title="Search" width="600px" border="normal"
apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
viewModel="@id('vm') @init('demo.getting_started.mvvm.SearchViewModel')"
binder="@id('b') @init('demo.getting_started.mvvm.AnnotateBinderExt',queueName='myqueue',queueScope='session')">
<hbox align="center">
    Keyword:
    <textbox id="txt" value="@bind(vm.keyword)" />
    Result:
    <textbox value="@load(vm.keyword)" />
</hbox></window>
```

and one of them change the value of the textfield I want update the value of the label for the other users.

I'm trying to work with the `eventQueue` but couldn't out how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your almost there.

The reason why it doesn't change is because @notifychange is propably called from a `Command` in stead of a `GlobalCommand`.

Take a look at [this small talk what I wrote.](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2014/March/Chat_with_Global_Command)

`@Command` is always the same viewmodel, `@GlobalCommand` can reach out to other viewmodels in the binders scope.